# Can not change div height dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

I have a DIV:
`<div class="div_tab" id="div3"> </div>`

Its properties are defined:

```
.div_tab {
    top:0;
    position: sticky; /* make the table heads sticky */
    display: inline-block;
    height : 500px;
    width :auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: auto;
    border : 1px black solid;
    padding:0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

It really have assigned height.
But when I change height:

```
this.tabDiv.setAttribute("height",px); // px is calculated
this.tabDiv.setAttribute("max-height", px);
```

Height does not change.
When I ask attribute value:
`alert(this.tabDiv.getAttribute("height"));`

I see value of "px".
How can I change div's height?

Comment: `this.tabDiv.style.height = px`

Comment: ```this.tabDiv.style.height=px; ```
top of the div also changed - WHY?

Answer (score 1):

[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) is typically used to set HTML *attributes*, not CSS properties:

You can try using *style* property to set the CSS property like the following way:

```
var heightPx = "200px";
var tabDiv = document.getElementById("div3");
tabDiv.style.height = heightPx;
tabDiv.style.maxHeight = heightPx;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('div3').style.height = px;
```

try this way.